# Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort' when using Chromedriver in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the restaurant names & their phone no.'s from https://www.manta.com/ website. I am using selenium to automate the whole task since the website is dynamic in nature and while running the python code I got the following
"Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'." and got empty list as the output.

Can u guys help me point out where I went wrong and also suggest me any books or websites where I can learn how to scrape dynamic websites ?

This is my python code for your reference.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers')

# Set Chrome options for running in headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# Create a new ChromeDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

# URL of the website you want to scrape
url ="https://www.manta.com/search?search=Restaurants&context=unknown&search_source=nav&city=Dallas&state=Texas&country=United%20States&pt=32.7936%2C-96.7662&device=desktop&screenResolution=1280x720"

# Navigate to the website
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# Find all the restaurant shop cards
listings = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")

print(listings) #print all the restaurant shop cards

# Close the driver and quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

**This is the error I got in my vscode**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49483/devtools/browser/88be036f-53d8-4f6a-b9ff-5b103ad5e6ff
[0525/152704.760:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", 
source:  (0)
[0525/152705.055:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", 
source:  (0)
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the website use cloudflare for Bot detection and blocks your selenium driver Chrome instance from loading the page

I have updated your locators to get all the shop card and print their text and used [undetected_chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) whichdoes not trigger anti-bot services like Cloudfare and Automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

Full code

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new ChromeDriver instance
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

# URL of the website you want to scrape
url = "https://www.manta.com/search?search=Restaurants&context=unknown&search_source=nav&city=Dallas&state=Texas&country=United%20States&pt=32.7936%2C-96.7662&device=desktop&screenResolution=1280x720"

# Navigate to the website
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
# Find all the restaurant shop cards
listings = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div")
# print all the restaurant shop cards
for listing in listings:
    print(listing.text)

# Close the driver and quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

Prints

```
QualitY Restaurants Dallas
1130 S Bowen Rd
Dallas, TX
(336) 536-4955
Visit Website
CLAIMED
Categori...
```

Comment: try updated code for headless

Comment: It is working but everytime I run the script the Gui gets activated and I don't want that to happen .So, how can i make the script run in headless mode and also handle pagination to the next page ?

Comment: And I also got these errors after the code ran successfuly and displayed the output and                                                                                                          Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x000001BEBD4BE520>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 800, in __del__ 
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid